# How to make a button that looks like its poping out like this in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to create in flutter a button like the one bellow:

[image]

This is what I managed to do:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
Container(
      width: sc.war(70.6),
      height: 50,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
        gradient: SColors.ONE_THOUSAND_POINTS_ASSOCIATE_PROGRAM_TITLE_GRADIENT
      ),
      child: FlatButton(
        onPressed: (){
          _validateUserInputs();
        },
        child: AutoSizeText(widget._loginPageMV.loginHint,
            minFontSize: 14,
            maxFontSize: 18,
            maxLines: 1,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 16,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
              letterSpacing: 0.2,
            )
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Can someone help me to achive this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

A raised button is based on a Material widget whose Material.elevation increases when the button is pressed.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RaisedButton-class.html